# Use reflection to get all extended types with Serializableattriubte

Tags: c#, reflection, datacontractserializer

Is it possible to get all extending class types which explicitly have the Serializable attribute defined in them?

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType("GetKnownTypes");
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public Type[] GetKnownTypes(){
        return all classes which extend this class
        AND explicitly have the [Serializable] attribute
    }   
}

public class DoNotWant : BaseClass {}

[Serializable]
public class Want : BaseClass {}
```

So GetKnownTypes will return the class 'Want', as it extends BaseClass and explicitly has the attribute Serializable whilst DoNotWant does not contain the attribute Serializable explicitly

Thank you

Edit :: 
I don't believe IsSerializable is accurate to rely on, as it seems to always be true (I'm not sure if this is because the BaseClass is Serializable or not)

Comment: The scenario is confusing, because WCF/DataContract doesn't **care** about [Serializable], so we would not expect to see it. Also, as a compiler detail [Serializable] maps to the same CLI flag that underpins IsSerializable (it is not actually implemented as an attribute... No: I really mean that) - however, it may vary with inheritance. However, if all the types are in the same assembly, then it should be easy enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested, but something like:

```
var types = typeof(BaseClass).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t =>
    t.IsClass && t.BaseType == typeof(BaseClass)
    && Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(SerializableAttribute))).ToArray();
```

Comment: Odd. My code is almost identical to this, but didn't work. I'll try to spot the different between the two now. Thank you.